# Handling Unknown Host Exception

Tags: java, android

When trying to send data to php server from android application using following code -

```
  @Override
        protected ServerResponseBean doInBackground(LoginBean... params) {
            String innerResult="-1";
            ServerResponseBean objSRBean = null;
            DefaultHttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
            try{
                HttpPost request =new HttpPost(UPDATE_LOGIN_LOCATION_URL);
                List<NameValuePair> param=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                param.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ID, params[0].getLoginID()+""));
                UrlEncodedFormEntity entity=new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param);
                request.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                if(response!=null){
                InputSource in = new InputSource(response.getEntity().getContent());
                InputStream isr=in.getByteStream();
                innerResult= readData(isr);
                isr.close();
                }
            }catch(UnknownHostException uhe){uhe.printStackTrace();}
                  catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

The above code works fine but sometimes application get crashed due to UnknownHostException where as my server is working fine.Even I have added validation for internet connection availability i.e if connection is available then only execute task in background otherwise ask user to enable internet connection.

Provide your suggestions to handle the exception.

Comment: It happen sometimes when you are running app in the emulator. just restart the emulator will solve the problem. If happen with device then make sure you added the internet permission in right place.

Comment: Order of my permissions are -                                  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: @sunil I am working on device.I need to avoid my application from being crashed.

Comment: When doing any sort of networking, your code should **always** be prepared to catch an unexpected IOException.  They can and will happen, even if you coded it perfectly.  Best practice when an HTTP request fails is to try again with some sort of backoff approach and/or retry count before signaling failure to the feature code.

Comment: @selbie Thanks, but if I go for recursion then it will go for infinite loop until it doesn't get proper netwark signals to communicate. That will lead to ANR.